# R: Creating a single vector using elements from two separate vectors

Tags: r, vector, sequence

I'm trying to efficiently create a vector of sequences using a vector of the starting values and end values, but I am having a rough time coming up with a clean way to do so.

I attempted to cbind the vectors into a matrix and use the apply() function in conjunction with the seq() function, but that didn't yield what I wanted.

For example, if we have the following:

```r
start <- c(1, 12, 19)
end <- c(5, 16, 23)
```

I would want to combine these somehow and get:

```r
1 2 3 4 5 12 13 14 15 16 19 20 21 22 23
```

(In the actual problem there are 10,000 such sequences, not just 3). Cheers!

Comment: Use `c(mapply(\`:\`, start, end))`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh geez, I guess I didn't know how to word my question while searching. Thanks for indulging me anyways!